# Derivative Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{e^{xy^2}}{y}dy$$

Where am I going wrong?

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{e^{xy^2}}{y}dy = & \frac{d}{dx} ( F(\sqrt{x} ) - F(x))\\
= & \frac{F'(\sqrt{x} )}{2\sqrt{x}} - F'(x))\\
= & \frac{e^{x(\sqrt{x})^2}}{2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}} - \frac{e^{xx^2}}{x}\\
= & \frac{e^{x^2} - 2e^{x^3}}{2x}
\end{align*}$$

The alternatives to this question were

a) $\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}$

b) $\frac{3e^{x^3}}{2x}$

c) $2e^{x^2} - 3e^{x^3}$

d) $\frac{ 2e^{x^2} - 3e^{x^3} }{2x}$

e) $\frac{ 2e^{x^2} + 3e^{x^3} }{2x}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added the possible answers @abiessu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have from [Leibniz's Rule for Differentiating Under the Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{\sqrt x}\frac{e^{xy^2}}{y}\,dy&=\color{blue}{\underbrace{\int_x^{\sqrt x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{e^{xy^2}}{y}\right)\,dy}_{\text{The Ommitted Term}}}+\color{red}{\underbrace{\left(\frac1{2\sqrt x}\frac{e^{x^2}}{\sqrt x}-\frac{e^{x^3}}{x}\right)}_{\text{This part was correct}}}\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\left(\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}-\frac{e^{x^3}}{2x}\right)}+\color{red}{\left(\frac{e^{x^2}}{2 x}-\frac{e^{x^3}}{x}\right)}\\\\
&=\frac{2e^{x^2}-3e^{x^3}}{2x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you Mark! Helped too much

Comment: You're welcome Jackson.  My pleasure.